# Why are interfaces not strongly typed?

Tags: vb.net, interface, strong-typing

I have the following code compiles without issue.  Of course, I get an invalid cast exception when executing the `Dim C As IDoThingsC = GetThing_C()`.  Am I missing something?  Would you ever want to return an object that does not meet the interface requirement for a function return value?

```
Public Class ClassA

  Public Sub DoThings_A()
    Debug.Print("Doing A things...")
  End Sub

End Class


Public Class ClassB
  Implements IDoThingsC

  Public Sub DoThings_B()
    Debug.Print("Doing B things...")
  End Sub

  Public Sub DoThings_C() Implements IDoThingsC.DoThings_C
    Debug.Print("Doing C things...")
  End Sub

End Class


Public Interface IDoThingsC

  Sub DoThings_C()

End Interface


Public Class aTest

  Public Sub Test()

    Dim C As IDoThingsC = GetThing_C()
    C.DoThings_C()

  End Sub


  Public Function GetThing_C() As IDoThingsC

    Dim Thing As ClassA = New ClassA
    Thing.DoThings_A()

    Return Thing

  End Function


End Class
```

Comment: I don't see how it gets compiled? Am I missing something?

Comment: Does this *really* compile without problems? I would think that "GetThing_C" would not compiled since it attempts to return a ClassA instance as IDoThingsC interface, which it does not implement.

Comment: That's what I thought.  It compiles in Visual Studio 2005 and in Visual Studio 2010 Beta 2.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [`Option Strict On`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) at the top of your source code file to catch problems like this.  You'll get a compile time error instead of a runtime error:

```
error BC30512: Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'ClassA' to 'IDoThingsC'.
```

Comment: Is it *still* possible to write VB code in this this-will-compile-cross-my-fingers-and-hope-to-die optimistic way? Why hasn't this been removed already?

Comment: Of course.  Even better -- I have changed the Option Strict option in the compile options of the project (this way I don't have to add it to every code module).

Answer (score 1):

Taken from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5fsszz9(VS.80).aspx

> When converting between data types,
>   the Visual Basic compiler can operate
>   under strict or permissive type
>   semantics. If strict type semantics
>   are in effect, only widening
>   conversions are permitted implicitly,
>   and narrowing conversions must be
>   explicit. Under permissive type
>   semantics, you can attempt all
>   widening and narrowing conversions
>   implicitly. Type semantics apply to
>   conversions between all data types,
>   including object types.

Answer (score 0):

Option Strict will solve this problem. But also "ClassA" doesn't implement any interface. So, switching Class A's definition to the following will solve your problem:

```
Public Class ClassA
  Implements IDoThingsC

  Public Sub DoThings_A()
    Debug.Print("Doing A things...")
  End Sub

End Class
```